# Vigenere Cipher error in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015, console-application, vigenere

I am creating a vigenere cipher in c++ and when i run the code it has an error says: **(Press Retry to debug the application)
ConsoleApplication2.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP140D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xstring
Line: 1681
Expression: string subscript out of range
For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
(Press Retry to debug the application)
ConsoleApplication2.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
The program '[3668] ConsoleApplication2.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).** 
here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string plaintext, key, Result;
    int k = 0;
    cout << "Enter the plain text: ";
    cin >> plaintext;
    cout << "Enter the key word: ";
    cin >> key;

    for (int i=0; i<plaintext.length(); i++)
    {
        Result[i] = (((plaintext[i] - 97) + (key[k] - 97)) % 26) + 97;
        k++;
        if (k == 6)
            (k = 0);
    }

    cout << "    \n\n\n";
    for (int i=0; i<plaintext.length(); i++)
        cout <<" "<< Result[i];
    cout << "\n\n\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The error is in the for statement `for (int i=0; i<plaintext.length(); i++)`it says something about the < sign and I don't know why. Any help? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You never set a size for `Result` so any `i` you use in

```
Result[i] = (((plaintext[i] - 97) + (key[k] - 97)) % 26) + 97;
```

is invalid.  You need to first set a size for `Result`.  You could use something like

```
string plaintext, key, Result;
int k = 0;
cout << "Enter the plain text: ";
cin >> plaintext;
cout << "Enter the key word: ";
cin >> key;
Result.resize(plaintext.size());
//...
```

Comment: do I have to copy this Result.resize(plaintext.size()); or is there more? @NathanOliver

Comment: @warren from what I saw yes but you could have other issues.  This just fixes the access violation.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
key[k]
```

How do you check that the index k < `key.length()` ? The variable `k` is bounded in [0,5] but how do you know that `key.length() < 5'?